# how can I effectively put my script to sleep for an accurate amount of miliseconds?

Tags: php, c, timer, cpu-time

I wrote the following myscript.php:

```
<?php
$count=0;
$start=microtime(true);
while ((microtime(true)-$start)<1) {
        usleep(1000);
        $count++;
}
echo $count;
?>
```

Instead of a number close to 1000, when I run `php -f myscript.php` on my CentOS 2.6.32 x64 kernel (windows 7 host) I get outputs like 35,43,76,543,44,39,29,38... What can I do?

EDIT: I also tried `time_nanosleep(0,1000000)` and C code using `usleep()` and `clock_gettime()` instead, with the same results.

Comment: Out of interest why do you want to sleep? (I'm just curious if you have a bigger issue that could be solved differently) ;-)

Comment: There isn't much you can do. `usleep` does no guarantee at all that your script will be awakened precisely after that amount of time; instead it says that it will sleep for *at least* that long, and that the actual duration may be increased because of system latencies and possible limitations in timer resolution. Then add PHP's overhead to that.

Comment: I'm trying to generate real time events for a simulation, so I can test my web application's performance (the app tracks, processes and displays changes on a log file in real time). An overhead of a thousand times seems quite a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be overhead in PHP, or it could be that `microtime()` and `usleep()` in PHP aren't that accurate.  It would be interesting to see what similar code in C does.

[This](http://tdistler.com/2010/06/27/high-performance-timing-on-linux-windows) article has an interesting discussion on accurate timing.

And [this](https://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf) article by VMWare on timing in virtual machines may be of interest.

Comment: Well this is definitely the problem (I tried C code using `usleep` and `clock_gettime` with the same results) but the article didn't help me much. Since I am using virtualization on a windows host I apparently have a lower resolution (like 7.5ms) but it's still a lot more than I'm actually getting. What do I need, a real time Kernel for this?